# Threaded posting of many requests to same url

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, faraday, typhoeus

I've constructed a json block like this:

```
data = {
    "url" : "http://www.example.com/post",
    "postdata" : [
        { "key1" : "value1" },
        { "key2" : "value2" },
        { "key3" : "value3" },
        { "key4" : "value4" },
        { "key5" : "value5" },
        { "key6" : "value6" }
    ]
}
```

I am attempting to post each block in 'postdata' in parallel (say a pool of 2) to the same 'url'. I've attempted to use Faraday, Typhoeus, and Parallel, but in doing so I have not encountered a functioning use case.

Ideally I'd like to use Typhoeus::Hydra or Faraday, passing the 'data' object to it, and pooling on data['postdata'] using data['url'] as the endpoint, but I've come up empty handed. Mostly I run into the case where I need to have a data array like:

```
[
    { "url" : "http://...",
      "data" : { "key1" : "value1" },
    { "url" : "http://...",
      "data" : { "key2" : "value2" },
    { "url" : "http://...",
      "data" : { "key3" : "value3" }
]
```

But I'd obviously like to avoid such duplication.

End goal: Post potentially 100s of json bodies to the same url in parallel, pooling by a limited (say 10) at a time. Can anyone help guide me down the right path?

Disclaimer: This is an internal endpoint, so nothing nefarious.

Solution based off tadman:

```
class BatchWrapper
  def initialize(data, offset)
    @data = data
    @offset = offset
  end

  def as_json
    @data['postdata'][@offset]
  end
end

q = Queue.new

data['postdata'].each_index do |i|
  q << BatchWrapper.new(data, i)
end

t = Thread.new do
  n = q.size
  n.times do |i|
    value = q.pop
    res = http.post(data['url'], value.as_json)
    puts res
    puts "consumed #{value.as_json}"
  end
end

t.join
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual strategy with this is where you remap your source data into something more digestible, then split that out across either a number of worker threads or through some kind of async event-driven method such as you'd use in EventMachine.

Threads are easier to understand, and then you can use the [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Queue.html) structure to batch up work for each thread to consume.

Break out your jobs into a series of objects, jam those objects into the queue, and then spin up N threads to work through those queues.

Since you're using threads, it's okay to use shared data. For example, you can have a thin wrapper object that, given a structure in that format, captures the offset you're sending:

```
class BatchWrapper
  def initialize(data, offset)
    @data = data
    @offset = offset
  end

  def as_json
    @data['postdata'][@offset]
  end
end
```

Then just stuff in one of these objects for each request you're intending to make:

```
q = Queue.new

data['postdata'].each_index do |i|
  q << BatchWrapper.new(data, i)
end
```

Then you can spin through the queue in a worker:

```
Thread.new do
  while (wrapper = q.pop)
    # Send it...
    make_request(wrapper.to_json)
  end
end
```

The wrapper approach allows you to compose exactly what data is shared from that main object and what's request-specific, plus do any necessary restructuring on the data itself. The `as_json` method returns what the `to_json` method ends up encoding, so you have complete control there.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: Elaborating on this, I ended up with inside of a "t = Thread.new do", the following:

n = q.size ; n.times do | i| ; value = q.pop ; res = req(data['url'], value.as_json) ; puts res

Seems to have worked as it outputs index 1 for every iteration (since it's popping), and each json block (value.as_json).

Comment: In general code the queue size may change over time, so it's best to not depend on any particular length. A simple way to kill off all the workers when they're done is to inject N jobs in there that represent "stop processing" and break the threads out of their loop.